# Is it possible to create a clustered stacked column chart using Google Charts

Tags: javascript, api, graph, charts

Looked everywhere and can't find anything, is it possible to create a graph like the below with the double x-axis label clusters, using google charts api?

[image]

Comment: Look at [stacked bar charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#stacked-bar-charts) in Google Charts

Comment: Yeah I can make the stacked chart, just can't figure out how to get the double labels at the bottom to group up.

Comment: you could use multiple charts beside each other, one chart for each data group, only show y-axis on first chart, use h-axis title for group name